# Should Web Applications meta have tag [site-recommendation]?

Tags: discussion, tags

To quote from the Usage guide for tag [site-recommendation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) (applied ~5 times, once a duplicate):

> Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

For the same tag on META: (applied 1,576 times – I assume their statistics are reliable):

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, you don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

<sup>Aside: Is one of the above plagiarism?</sup>

We already have tag [scope](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) ([You should always favor existing tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)) to cover what is and is not off topic for Web Applications, its Usage guide:

> Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic on this site, and why.

and with a highly slumberous meta are unlikely to provide a *fast* response, relative to [META](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (who are receiving 7.7k visits per day).

In addition, META is shown as having twice as many users, so presumably a broader representation of the 170 SE communities, so possibly better *quality* of response.

SO meta has such a tag, but 77 out of the 224 Qs there are Closed.

SU meta has 2 Qs so tagged.

Server Fault meta, Ask Different meta, TSE meta (and maybe others) have no such tag.

If a Q is deemed off topic here it might be a greater service to OP to point to where to ask where to ask than to point directly to another specialist SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(moved down from a comment)

I'd say that site recommendations are best handled by the mother Meta. One might argue that a Web Apps user knows some of the other sites (SU, Android Enthusiasts) pretty well, but for broader questions ("Does this belong on SF?" I don't think we'd be of much service. As for the overarching question of the tag, we don't need it if we don't have questions that demand it.

Answer (score 0):

While Meta Stack Exchange is probably a better choice for such questions, I think such questions are just fine here. Most of the active people on Web Apps participate in more than one Stack Exchange site, so may have particular insights and can recommend a site without forcing the user to go to *yet another* place to find where to ask their question.

I am *against* getting rid of the tag.